# Drawing animation on combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, animation, combobox, picturebox

There is a lot of already answered question and examples about how to draw images within combobox. But I haven't found any examples how to draw animations within combobox.

The gif animation I use is (it's transparent): 
[image]

And the result I want to achieve is somethink like this: 
[image]

I'm using Windows Forms and .Net 3.5.
All ways of achieving that, I thought about, were:
1. Use Graphics.DrawImage in ComboBox's DrawItem handler. But the image was drawn statically, there was no anmation.
2. Use PictureBox to show animation and then somehow resize it and place over the ComboBox.

For second soultion I used the following code:

```
pictureBox1 = new PictureBox();
pictureBox1.Image = Resource.myImage;
pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
//3 is used just for try to fit image into "white" area of ComboBox
pictureBox1.ClientSize = new Size(comboBox1.Size.Height-3, comboBox1.Size.Height-3);
pictureBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
pictureBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Left;
pictureBox1.Parent = this.comboBox1;
pictureBox1.Enabled = true;
pictureBox1.Visible = true;
```

But in result I've got this:
[image]

It's animated, but picturebox is drawn on ComboBox edges and it looks bad.

So, can anyone give me an advice or some help to achive this?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**
**My final solution that worked:**

```
pictureBox1 = new PictureBox();
pictureBox1.Image = Resource1.myImage;
pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
pictureBox1.ClientSize = new Size(comboBox1.Size.Height - SystemInformation.Border3DSize.Height,  comboBox1.Size.Height - (2 * SystemInformation.Border3DSize.Height));
pictureBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
pictureBox1.Location = new Point(SystemInformation.Border3DSize.Width, SystemInformation.Border3DSize.Height);
pictureBox1.Parent = this.comboBox1;
pictureBox1.Enabled = true;
pictureBox1.Visible = true;
```

Thank you all! You help me a lot!

Comment: Have you tried setting the Size of the PictureBox instead of the ClientSize?

Comment: @hometoast yes, I've tried but there were no visible changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
            pictureBox1 = new PictureBox();
            pictureBox1.Image = Resource.myImage;
            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            //2 is used just for try to fit image into "white" area of ComboBox
            pictureBox1.ClientSize = new Size(comboBox1.Size.Height - 2, comboBox1.Size.Height - 2);
            pictureBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            pictureBox1.Left = 1;
            pictureBox1.Top = 1;
            pictureBox1.Parent = this.comboBox1;
            pictureBox1.Enabled = true;
            pictureBox1.Visible = true;
```

Comment: Worth noting: you can get the size of the border (instead of trying to guess at it) with [SystemInformation.BorderSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.bordersize.aspx])

Comment: Great! Thank's a lot! I've forgot about Left and Top, shame on me! (I'm new in GUI programming, so complex UIs are hell for me)

Answer (score 1):

It might be then a tad *too* small, but it would fit, if you set the size of your combobox to `pictureBox1.Size = new Size(comboBox1.ItemHeight, comboBox1.ItemHeight)`.

Or set the height and width to `2*SystemInformation.3DBorderSize`

Comment: Thanks for answer! I've tried your solution but ItemHeight too small (it's value is 13 in comparison with ComboBox.Size.Height which is 21). But anyway thanks for SystemInformation.Border3DSize, I used it in my final solution!

Answer (score 1):

remove the code that sets the "Dock" property. Setting this causes the layout manager to ignore size/location settings.

Instead, set the `Size` property and the `Location` property to specific values.

Something like:

```
pictureBox3.Size = new Size(comboBox1.Size.Height-3, comboBox1.Size.Height-3);
pictureBox3.Location = new Point(0, 3);
```

You may have to adjust these to get the extact position you need.

Comment: @ekholm That doesn't mean a user can't try to provide an answer.